# Proving the existence of complement subspace using quotients

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, change-of-basis

I want to prove the existence of complement subspace using the notion of quotient spaces, i.e. let $W \subseteq V$ be a subspace, then there is a subspace $U \subseteq V$ such that $V = W \oplus U$.

Say $W \subseteq V$ has basis $\{w_1, \cdots, w_m\}$, then $V / W$ is a vector space. Let $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ be a basis of $V /W$. Lift it back to $V$ using the inverse projection, i.e.  let $u_i = v \in V$ such that $v + W = x_i$, for $i = 1, \cdots, n$. Then I think it makes intuitive sense that $\{w_1, \cdots, w_m, u_1, \cdots, u_n\}$ is a basis of $V$. But I don't quite see how I can show that rigorously. I guess it has something to do with how the projection map is set up. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use that the images of the vectors $u_1, \dots, u_n$ under the projection map $\pi \colon V \to V/W$ form a basis, together with the fact that any element $v \in V$ is mapped to zero by $\pi$ if and only if $v \in W$, i.e. if and only if $v$ is a linear combination of $w_1, \dots, w_n$.

Let's see how to use this to prove $\{ w_1, \dots ,w_m, u_1, \dots ,u_n\}$ spans $V$. Let $v \in V$, then since $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ is a basis of $V/W$ we have
$$
\pi(v) = \mu_1 x_1 + \cdots + \mu_n x_n
$$
for some scalars $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n$. Now notice that $\pi(\mu_1 u_1 + \cdots + \mu_n u_n)$ equals the sum above, so $v - (\mu_1 u_1 + \cdots + \mu_n u_n) \in \ker(\pi) = W = \text{span}\{ w_1, \dots, w_n \}$. So then
$$
v - (\mu_1 u_1 + \cdots + \mu_n u_n) = \lambda_1 w_1 + \dots + \lambda_n w_n
$$
for some scalars $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. This shows $v$ is a linear combination of $\{ w_1, \dots ,w_m, u_1, \dots ,u_n \}$ , and so this is a spanning set.

The proof that it is a linear independent set is similar: given some linear dependence relation, consider the image in $V/W$ and use that the elements $\pi(u_i) = x_i$ (where $i = 1, \dots, n$) form a basis of $V/W$. Can you complete this proof yourself?

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I do have a question about showing the spanning set is linearly independent. Does "given some linear dependence relation" mean let $v = $a linear combination of $\{w_1,…,w_m,u_1,…,u_n\}$?

Comment: What I mean by this is a relation of the form $\lambda_1 w_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n w_n + \mu_1 u_1 + \cdots + \mu_m u_m = 0$ for some scalars $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n, \mu_1, \dots, \mu_m$. The definition of linear independence which I find easiest to work with is that, if such a relation exists, then necessarily $\lambda_i = 0$ and $\mu_j = 0$ for every $i$ and $j$ - so this is the definition of linear independence I had in mind with this suggestion.

Comment: I see! So $\pi(w_i) = [0]$ for all $i$ since $w_i \in W$, and $\pi(u_j) = x_j$ for all $j$ by definition. Hence $\pi(\lambda_1 w_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n w_n + \mu_1 u_1 + \cdots + \mu_m u_m) = \mu_1 x_1 + \cdots + \mu_m x_m = 0$, which implies $\mu_j = 0$ for all $j$, right?

Comment: Yes! Nicely done.